# Why there can't be an isotropic radiator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, symmetry, multipole-expansion

Why there can't be an [isotropic radiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_radiator)? I know you can prove it using Maxwell's equations but I don't see how.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_radiator)? If so, what is unclear about the proof?

Comment: @Chemomechanics if one is asking about a proof in a mathematical sense then the wikipedia's argument is not quite a "proof" because the field is never *exactly* tangential to a sphere centered around the radiator, in fact it can never be completely tangential at any a *finite* distance as it can be seen from Ignatowski's equations. I am not saying that the argument is wrong, just that it is not quite complete. I think it needs some more extensive $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ argument *in addition* to the one usually provided.

Comment: But more importantly the "hairy ball" theorem would only restrict a radiation pattern that is linearly polarized. Matzner and McDonald synthesized an *elliptically* polarized isotropic radiation that is not restricted by the "hairy ball" theorem and has a spherically uniform *magnitude*, which what is really expected from a spherically uniform radiator, see here https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.physics/0312023

Comment: now that @buzz deleted my perfectly correct answer and converted into a comment without any explanation it will soon disappear in cyberspace. Wow, buzarre bizz.

Comment: @hyportnex:  Your answer was written as a response to a comment, and wouldn't have made much sense without it if *that* comment had gone away.  So I flagged it as "not an answer".  If you rewrote the content of your answer so that it could stand on its own, with minimal reference to other comments, it would probably be fine.

Comment: @MichaleSeifert but now there is no answer to rewrite, so why don't you write one. In fact here is a good question with at best an incomplete and at worst wrong explanation in wikipedia as Matzner-McDonald showed this more than 20 years ago, or Shtrikhman 30 years ago!  And if somebody wished to find the right answer in the phys SE only my fungible comments will be there. I am sure you or Buzz know 20dB more physics than I, so write the proper answer for all students to come, or restore my answer as was written and ask me in a comment to cure its format per local regulations.

Comment: @hyportnex Your answer should still be visible to you if you want to edit it. If you edit it into a standalone answer flag it for moderator attention and we'll undelete it.